# jquery post request ajax with content type

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

hello i have the code bellow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 14         $(document).ready(function() {
 15                 $('#find').click(function(){
 16                         
 17                         var amount = $('#amount').val();
 18 
 19                         $.ajax({
 20                                 type: "POST",
 21                                 contentType: "text/xml;charset=utf-8",
 22                                 url: "questions.php",
 23                                 data: {'amount': amount},
 24                                 success: function(data){
 25                                         
 26                                         $('#results').show();
 27                         
 28                                         
 29                                         $('#results').html(data);
 30                                 }
 31                         });
 32                 });
 33         });
 34     </script>
```

and my php script has the code below

```
5 $search_term = $_POST['amount'];
6 echo $search_term;
```

if i remove line 21 with content type thing i get the input as output but with that i get nothing as output! The thing is that i really need the content type thing so any info on that would be really helpful!

Comment: Does PHP get the data at all?

Comment: i guess no (i get no output) if i have the content type thing! if i remove it yeah because i get the echo shit!

Comment: Remove line 21 from your js. var_dump( $_POST ); in the php file receiving the request. Does it give you what you want? You could also add dataType: 'JSON' to your ajax params.

Comment: `The thing is that i really need the content type thing` You aren't sending xml, so why do you need the content type to specify xml?

Comment: if i remove that line i get array(0) { } but i need that line i need setting the content type on post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending the data as form data, but declaring the sent data as XML.  PHP cannot parse JSON data when it's expecting XML so doesn't return anything.  And it's optional to set `contentType`.

From the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> contentType Default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
>   When sending data to the server, use this content type.
>   Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which
>   is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to
>   $.ajax(), then it'll always be sent to the server (even if no data is
>   sent). If no charset is specified, data will be transmitted to the
>   server using the server's default charset; you must decode this
>   appropriately on the server side.

Comment: He isn't sending JSON just regular `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data

Comment: Just leave out that line unless you're actually sending XML to the server.

Comment: but the server complains about the request check this out http://stackoverflowsearch.comeze.com/

Comment: I can't see the server code from the front-end, so I guess I don't know what the problem is. :-/

Comment: It's definitely a problem in your PHP file. I think using `print_r` converts the array to a string. Try just using `echo`.

Comment: no i dont think that is the problem cause with mamp works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Change line 21

```
contentType: "text/xml;charset=utf-8",
```

to

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: the problem is that i get that error here http://stackoverflowsearch.comeze.com/ so that doesn't solve my problem